# Is what I did common? Could it cause possible issues? Retook my Ph.D program's equivalent of some Master's courses I took and they count as electives

Tags: research-process, graduate-school, coursework, transcript-of-records, credentials

I'm a fourth year Ph.D candidate in the US studying Experimental Psychology at a regional college. I also got my Master's in Experimental Psychology back in December 2020.

My Ph.D program accepted my Master's in full since it was also in Experimental Psychology. However, I decided to take my program's equivalent of some Master's courses because I took the way my Ph.D program phrased "the first two years are similar to the Master's program" part of the handbook literally. What I did was take courses normally required of students who are going for their Master's in the program and they ended up getting approved as electives for my Ph.D. The only course repeats my first advisor wanted me to take were 2 credit hours of first year seminar, her cognitive psychology class (my main discipline is cognitive), and liked that I took their quantitative methods class at the Ph.D program since my first advisor noticed I had a tendency to not pay attention to the data in studies that much at the time. I also took a History & Systems course in Psychology as well, which was something my first program did not even offer at all. That's 11 total credit hours my advisor was OK were electives in this case (I needed 12 minimum and up to 18 maxium. Including transferred courses, I am at the maximum). My Ph.D programs equivalent of Developmental Psychology and Research Methods (only cause I got a low grade in it the first time during my MA) were ones that were repeats I took thinking I had to do it when I did not.

When I look at my graduate program's handbook now, there were some new courses I could've taken that didn't overlap with my Master's and I'm concerned that may be a potential problem. Could it be an issue to an employer possibly? Are there other contexts where this could be an issue?

Edit: Changed it to say "not pay attention" in regards to data analysis.

Comment: No employer is likely to look at the courses you took.

Comment: A lot of your questions seem to indicate insecurity about your program and progress. Perhaps you should find someone (a counsellor) to help with that generally.

Answer (score 4):

This and other questions of yours seem to suggest a focus of your concern on "the rules" and somehow suffering a consequence when someone discovers you haven't quite done the most optimal thing, like you will be discovered as a cheater and have something taken away from you.

Your education is yours. The courses you take are for your learning. There are also rules for your institution as far as what it means to earn a degree, but really your institution isn't the one who should care the most about whether you got the most out of your education. For them, it looks bad if a student doesn't graduate. They're not going to dig and find excuses to not grant you a degree after already approving your course of study.

The costs to you in doubling up work to make things easier are in the missed opportunity. If this decision costs you a job later it won't be because you got "caught" and denied based on some procedure, it'll be because, to take an example from another question, you don't have sufficient training in statistics for the job you're applying for, and someone else who does will get picked over you. Or you'll have grants or manuscripts rejected because you don't know how to propose appropriate analyses, and so your CV will come up short against someone else's. The same applies to courses where you did not earn the best grade: this may indicate that you have not mastered the material entirely. That's for you! The learning is yours, to apply to whatever else you do next.

Comment: I see your point. I nearly edited this into my post but I should note that my first advisor was super hands off with me to a fault. When I brought up courses I was taking, I distinctly remember her waving stating, "I don't want to hear it." Then, she just approved what I took already (and she didn't know outside of my Ph.D program's equivalent of stats - one of the classes I "doubled up" on - and when I took Cognitive Psychology with her. Cognitive was another "double," but she wanted me to take it with her. Although she didn't plan on me taking their stats either, she endorsed it.

Comment: @zzmondo1 I don't think anything in your comment relates to anything about my answer. It doesn't matter if your advisor was hands off or whose fault it is which courses you took. Your education is yours.

Comment: +1 for "Your education is yours."

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how "common" this is, but if it is acceptable to your current program then it is fine. In the US, the coursework in a doctoral program is usually to assure that the candidate (a) has a broad perspective of the overall field and (b) can pass the necessary comprehensive exams. Only then does one, in the common case, take the deep dive into specialized research in a narrow part of their field.

Most US doctoral students start with only a bachelors and so the graduate courses are deeper, generally speaking, than what happens in a US bachelors program. But it isn't really a matter of "collecting credits" but one of preparation for a career in research, usually academia, which will require both the broad and the narrow view.

I don't know if you are worried about your own situation, but if no one at your current institution has raised it by now, you should be fine. You might have progressed faster if the MS courses had really prepared you for comps/qualifiers (assuming they are needed) and you might not have had to spend the time taking the courses, but they seem to have done you no harm other than time spent. Or perhaps the opportunity to have taken other courses rather than repeat.

---

But, as to the "common" question: as a guess, I'd think most would probably prioritize finishing earlier over retaking courses (where possible) and many would prioritize learning something new over retaking courses. Or maybe that's just me.